# Angular 2 Tests - Provide RouteParams to route to /employees/:id/edit

Tags: jasmine, angular, karma-runner, angular2-routing

I have a component corresponding to the route `/employees/:id/edit`. Now I wish to write unit tests for it.

For that, I have following `RouteParams` in `beforeEachProviders` block:

```
provide(RouteParams, { useValue: new RouteParams({ id: '1' }) }
```

My guess was the `id` attribute will be replaced by the RouteParams mock. But when I log the current URL inside `it` block like:

```
console.log(window.location.href);
```

I get `LOG: 'http://localhost:9876/context.html'`

Also the innerHtml is empty.

So, Am I supposed to mock `RouteParams` differently?

**Component Code:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from 'angular2/core';
import { RouteParams, Router } from 'angular2/router';

import { Employee } from '../models/employee';
import { EmployeeDetailServiceComponent } from '../services/employee-detail-service.component';
import { EmployeeEditFormServiceComponent } from '../services/employee-edit-form-service.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'employee-edit-form',
  template: `
    <div class="container">
    <h3>Employee Edit Form</h3>
    <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #employeeForm="ngForm" *ngIf="currentEmployee != undefined">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" required [(ngModel)]="currentEmployee.name"
            ngControl="name"  #name="ngForm">
       <div [hidden]="name.valid || name.pristine" class="alert alert-danger">
         Name is required
       </div>
      </div>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="editEmployee()" [disabled]="!employeeForm.form.valid">Update</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  `,
  providers: [
    EmployeeDetailServiceComponent,
    EmployeeEditFormServiceComponent
  ]
})

export class EmployeeEditFormComponent implements OnInit {
  public currentEmployee: Employee;
  public errorMessage: string;

  constructor(
    private _router: Router,
    private _routeParams: RouteParams,
    private _detailService: EmployeeDetailServiceComponent,
    private _editService: EmployeeEditFormServiceComponent
  ){}

  ngOnInit() {
    let id = parseInt(this._routeParams.get('id'));
    this._detailService.getEmployee(id).subscribe(
                     employee => this.currentEmployee = employee
                   );
  }

  editEmployee() {
    this._editService.editEmployee(this.currentEmployee)
    .subscribe(
      employee => this.currentEmployee = employee,
      error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error,
      () => this._router.navigate(['EmployeeDetail', {id: this.currentEmployee.id}])
    );
  }
}
```

**Spec Code**

```
/// <reference path="../../typings/main/ambient/jasmine/jasmine.d.ts" />

import {
    it,
    describe,
    expect,
    TestComponentBuilder,
    injectAsync,
    setBaseTestProviders,
    beforeEachProviders,
    resetBaseTestProviders
} from "angular2/testing";
import {
    Component,
    provide,
    ApplicationRef
} from "angular2/core";
import {
    TEST_BROWSER_PLATFORM_PROVIDERS,
    TEST_BROWSER_APPLICATION_PROVIDERS
} from "angular2/platform/testing/browser";
import {
    ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    ROUTER_PRIMARY_COMPONENT,
    APP_BASE_HREF,
    Router,
    RouteParams,
    RouteRegistry
} from 'angular2/router';
import {RootRouter} from "angular2/src/router/router";
import {SpyLocation} from "angular2/src/mock/location_mock";
import {Location} from "angular2/src/router/location/location";
import {
    XHRBackend,
    HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    Response,
    ResponseOptions
} from "angular2/http";
import { MockApplicationRef } from 'angular2/src/mock/mock_application_ref';
import {
    MockBackend,
    MockConnection
} from "angular2/src/http/backends/mock_backend";
import { BrowserDomAdapter } from 'angular2/src/platform/browser/browser_adapter';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

import { AppComponent } from '../app.component';
import { EmployeeEditFormComponent } from './employee-edit-form.component';
import { EmployeeDetailServiceComponent } from '../services/employee-detail-service.component';
import { EmployeeEditFormServiceComponent } from '../services/employee-edit-form-service.component';


class MockEmployeeDetailServiceComponent {}

class MockEmployeeEditFormServiceComponent {}


@Component({
    template: '<employee-edit-form></employee-edit-form>',
    directives: [EmployeeEditFormComponent]
})
class TestMyEditForm extends EmployeeEditFormComponent{}


describe('Employee Edit Form Tests', () => {
    resetBaseTestProviders();
    setBaseTestProviders(
        TEST_BROWSER_PLATFORM_PROVIDERS,
        TEST_BROWSER_APPLICATION_PROVIDERS
    );
    beforeEachProviders(() => {
        return [
            ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,
            ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
            HTTP_PROVIDERS,
            EmployeeEditFormComponent,
            EmployeeDetailServiceComponent,
            EmployeeEditFormServiceComponent,
            provide(XHRBackend, {useClass: MockBackend}),
            provide(APP_BASE_HREF, {useValue: '/'}),
            provide(ROUTER_PRIMARY_COMPONENT, {useValue: AppComponent}),
            provide(ApplicationRef, {useClass: MockApplicationRef}),
            RouteRegistry,
            provide(Location, {useClass: SpyLocation}),
            provide(Router, {useClass: RootRouter}),
            provide(RouteParams, { useValue: new RouteParams({ id: '1' }) })
        ]
    });

    it('Should display the edit form of employees',
        injectAsync([XHRBackend, TestComponentBuilder], (backend, tcb) => {
            backend.connections.subscribe(
                (connection:MockConnection) => {
                    var options = new ResponseOptions({
                        body: {
                            "id": 1,
                            "name": "Roshan Shrestha"
                        }
                    });

                    var response = new Response(options);

                    connection.mockRespond(response);
                }
            );

            return tcb
                .createAsync(TestMyEditForm)
                .then((fixture) => {
                    fixture.detectChanges();
                    var comp = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
                    console.log(comp);
                });
        })
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the data you provided is contained within the `parameters` attribute of your injected `RouteParams`. When you configure the provider and specify it into the constructor of your component, the instance will be injected but the URL won't be updated since there is actually no routing involved here...

See the following sample:

```
beforeEachProviders(() => {
  return [
    provide(RouteParams, { useValue: new RouteParams({ id: '1' })
  ];
});

it('should access route params', injectAsync([TestComponentBuilder], (tcb: TestComponentBuilder) => {
  return tcb.createAsync(DropdownComponent)
    .then(fixture => {
      let comp: DropdownComponent = fixture.componentInstance;
      fixture.detectChanges();

      expect(comp.data.params).toEqual({ id: '1' });
  });
}));
```

Here is the corresponding component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'dropdown',
  template: `
    <div>Test</div>
  `
})
export class DropdownComponent {
  constructor(public data:RouteParams) {
  }
}
```

See the corresponding plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/pFmiyk?p=preview.

Comment: I am getting `undefined` with `comp.data`